# Xam.Plugins.Media for Android 7.0

Tags: xamarin.android, android-7.0-nougat

I must use Android 7 for my app because I am using .NETStandard libraries. Media plugin is not compatible with Android 7. Is there any way to keep my code and use Android 7?

```
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;

private async void TakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No camera", "No available camera", "OK");
                return;
            }
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                Directory = "",
                Name = ""
            });
            if (file == null) return;

            PathLabel.Text = file.AlbumPath;

            MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });
        }
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am having same issue. Only targeting Android 6 seems to fix it.  Did you find an alternative solution?